# How to add all controls of another form to a form in Winforms?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I tried using:

CoolForm.ActiveForm.Controls

but the count returns 0.

The main form that is shown is AppForm and has all the controls.

I want to add all the controls of CoolForm (which has 1 form) to be added to the main form (AppForm)

Is this possible?

Comment: I don't follow... can you explain more? What is CoolForm, is it your application name? What are you trying to achieve (not the copying) and why? There may be a different approach that's more appropriate.

Comment: CoolForm is the second form, AppForm is the main form. Trying to add all the controls of CoolForm to AppForm.

Comment: Form.ActiveForm is a static method which returns the currently active form in your app, not the active instance of a *specific* form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer, I had to instantiate CoolForm inside AppForm and then access its controls. But if there is a better way, let me know.

Comment: Where were you instantiating CoolForm before? Not in AppForm? You need to have the reference to an instance of a CoolForm to work with it's members.

Comment: Yeah I didn't know it was the case for forms.